# Android :cannot unit test android functions receiving NPE

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have just started unit testing in android. I cannot unit test android internal method to notify that data is changed (notifyDataSetChanged)and I am getting null pointer exception on this point. I am using mockito and power moockito to mock different objects.

```
 public void RecyclerView(String value,Bitmap image) {
  RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter

    }
```

My unit test is:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MainActivity.class})
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Mock
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Mock
    RecyclerView recycleview;
    @InjectMocks
    Activity activity;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mainactivity = new MainActivity();

    }

    @Test
    public void PopulateRecyleViewTest() {
        try {
            final RecyclerViewAdapter abc = PowerMockito.mock(RecyclerViewAdapter.class);


            PowerMockito.whenNew(RecyclerViewAdapter.class).withArguments(mainactivity).thenReturn(abc);
            doNothing().when(abc).notifyDataSetChanged(); //do nothing getting exception here
            mainactivity.recyclerView = recycleview;

            mainactivity.PopulateRecyleView("", bitmap);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any way to unit test this method so that notifydatasetchanged() do not give NPE(Null Pointer Exception)? I have read that power mockito is used to unit test final method but it does not seem to be unit testing notifyDataSetChanged which is final method. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Acc to Android documentation - "If your unit test has no dependencies or only has simple dependencies on Android, you should run your test on a local development machine"

Mockito/PowerMockito runs on your JVM.

```
@InjectMocks
Activity activity;
```

It is not straight forward to mock the activity that is why we have Instrumented Unit Tests. I see lot of problem's in the above test case. I think you should write instrumentation case in your case.

Use Mockito/PowerMockito where you have more of Java objects, like your presentation class (in MVP architecture) or any business logic.

Please checkout android documentation on testing [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/index.html).
This will give you proper picture of how and what should be your approach for writing unit test cases in Android.

Answer (score 0):

With Mockito 2.0 and above you can mock final classes and methods by adding a file. Check out this document: [Mock the unmockable: opt-in mocking of final classes/methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods)

Basically it states that you have to create the file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` then add the single line:

`mock-maker-inline`

After that you should be able to mock a final class or method. I had the same issue you had and this worked for me.